# Window Azure Mobile Service select Query issue. how to make query on same column of multiple value instead only single?

Tags: android, azure, azure-table-storage

I am working on android to access window azure database..

My qtn is How to make an query to access data based on single column but multiple values.?

Here is my code :

```
try {
            mClient = new MobileServiceClient(Constant.AZURE_URL, Constant.AZURE_API_KEY, getApplicationContext());
            mUsersTable = mClient.getTable(Users.class);        
             MobileServiceTable<Users> table = mClient.getTable(Constant.TABLE_USERS, Users.class);

                  table.where().field("id").eq(11)
                                .execute(new TableQueryCallback<Users>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(List<Users> result, int count,
                                            Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {

                                        if (exception != null) {
                                            Log.d("Exception at complete::",""+exception.getCause().getMessage());

                                        } else {
                                            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                                            for (Users users_obj : result) {
                                                System.out.println("NAMESS::::"+users_obj.getFirstName());

                                             //   userID_arr.add(users_obj.getFirstName());

                                            }

                                            //System.out.println("User Array"+userID_arr);

                                        }
                                    }
                              });           

               } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error Mobile Service Authentication", "There was an error creating the Mobile Service. Verify the URL");

        }
         catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

There for I am able to get complete row on the basis of single parameter in table.where().feilds.eq(11)................... so instead 11 i want to add dynamic values on .eq() ....what is approach in Android auzre to get values on multiple id request ?